# Making a Fibonacci function and cannot add correctly add/represent integers two digits or larger

Tags: c

This is a program to add Fibonacci numbers together. The function in question is hugeAdd. The integers add correctly to 8 however, once it hits 13 or higher it returns on incorrect value. The incorrect value being a memory address for the carry(1) but, the correct value for the ones position(3). Tried setting it manually however, it seems to not work for some reason because 'k' my counter variable declared in the for statement cannot be called even inside the for loop.

Note: Here is the smallest MCVE i could make. Throw a breakpoint at line 134 in Fibonacci.c and it will print added integers.

Fibonacci.h(This is the header file that contains struct def and etc)

```
#ifndef __FIBONACCI_H
#define __FIBONACCI_H

typedef struct HugeInteger
{
// a dynamically allocated array to hold the digits of a huge integer
int *digits;

// the number of digits in the huge integer (approx. equal to arraylength)
int length;
} HugeInteger;


// Functional Prototypes

HugeInteger *hugeAdd(HugeInteger *p, HugeInteger *q);

HugeInteger *hugeDestroyer(HugeInteger *p);

HugeInteger *parseString(char *str);

HugeInteger *parseInt(unsigned int n);

unsigned int *toUnsignedInt(HugeInteger *p);

HugeInteger *fib(int n);

double difficultyRating(void);

double hoursSpent(void);


#endif
```

Testcase4.c Class(Contains main function and test case to test function)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include "Fibonacci.h"

// print a HugeInteger (followed by a newline character)
void hugePrint(HugeInteger *p)
{
int i;

if (p == NULL || p->digits == NULL)
{
    printf("(null pointer)\n");
    return;
}

for (i = p->length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    printf("%d", p->digits[i]);
printf("\n");
}

int main(void)
{
int i;
HugeInteger *p;

for (i = 0; i <= 1000; i++)
{
    printf("F(%d) = ", i);
    hugePrint(p = fib(i));
    //p = fib(i);
    //hugeDestroyer(p);
}

return 0;
}
```

Fibonacci.c Class(This class has all the functions to run testcase4.c)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <math.h>
#include "Fibonacci.h"

HugeInteger *hugeAdd(HugeInteger *p, HugeInteger *q)
{
HugeInteger *hugerInt = malloc(sizeof(HugeInteger));

int overhead=1,i,j,results=0;
 int *resultArray = NULL;

if(p == NULL || q == NULL || hugerInt == NULL)
{
    return NULL;
}


if(p->length > q->length)
{
  resultArray = calloc(((p->length)+ overhead), sizeof(int));
  hugerInt->length = p->length;
  hugerInt->digits = malloc(sizeof(int) * (p->length + overhead));

  if(resultArray == NULL)
  {
      return NULL;
  }
  for(int k=0; k < p->length; k++)
  {
    if(k >= q->length)
    {
        results=p->digits[k];   //check for not skipping smaller int
        resultArray[k] = results + resultArray[k];
    }
    else{
 results = p->digits[k] + q->digits[k];
  if(results > 9 )
  {
      if(p->digits[k+1] == 0)
      {
          hugerInt->digits[k+1] = 1;
      }

      resultArray[k+1] = resultArray[k+1] + 1;

      results = results - 10;
    printf("length of resultArray is %d\n",p->length+1);
  }


      resultArray[k] = results;


  }
  }
}
else
{
  resultArray = calloc(((p->length)+ overhead)+ 1, sizeof(int));
  hugerInt->length = q->length;
  hugerInt->digits = malloc(sizeof(int) * (q->length)+ overhead);

  if(resultArray == NULL)
  {
      return NULL;
  }
  for(i=0; i < q->length; i++)
  {
   // printf("q length %d", q->length);
    if(i >= p->length) // Check if second struct passed is smaller then first one passed
    {
        results=q->digits[i];   //check for not skipping smaller int
        resultArray[i] = results;
    }
    else{
 results = q->digits[i] + p->digits[i];
  if(results > 9 )
  {
      printf("I is in larger then 9 check %d", i);
      if(p->digits[i+1] == 0)
      {
          hugerInt->digits[i+1] = 1;
      }

      printf("i is %d\n",i);
      printf("Assigning 1 to %d in resultarray\n", i);
      resultArray[i+1] = 1; // if value is greater then 9 the 1 carries and gets added to the result.(This is the part i think is going wrong) 

      results = results - 10;

    printf("length of resultArray is %d\n",p->length+1);
      printf("results:$d\n", results);
  }


      resultArray[i] = results; // Throws added values into array


    }
  }
}

printf("\n=================\n");
for(i=0; i < hugerInt->length; i++)
{
   hugerInt->digits[i] = resultArray[i];
}


printf("Result array at 0 is %d\n", resultArray[0]); // This is were the 
printf("Result array at 1 is %d\n", resultArray[1]); // added numbers are stored.
printf("Result array at 2 is %d\n", resultArray[2]);

printf("=====================\n");

free(resultArray);
return hugerInt;
} 

HugeInteger *fib(int n)
{
HugeInteger *fibInt = malloc(sizeof(HugeInteger));

HugeInteger *fatherFib = malloc(sizeof(HugeInteger));
HugeInteger *grandfatherFib = malloc(sizeof(HugeInteger));


int j=1,fatherLength=0,grandfatherLength=0,fibLength=0,result, overhead=1;
unsigned int father, grandFather, fib, tempFather, tempGrandfather, tempFib;

fatherFib->digits = calloc((n + overhead),sizeof(int) );
fibInt->digits = calloc((n+overhead),sizeof(int));

grandfatherFib->digits = calloc((n + overhead),sizeof(int) );

  fatherFib->length = 1;
 grandfatherFib->length = 1;
 fibInt->length = 1;

 if(n == 0)
 {
     fibInt->digits[0] = 0;
     return fibInt;
 }



for(int i=0; i < n; i++)
{


 if(i >= 1)
 {

  if(fatherFib->digits[0] >= 5 && grandfatherFib->digits[0] >= 5)
  {
  fibInt->length = 2;

  }
  else if(fatherFib->digits[1] >= 5 && grandfatherFib->digits[1] >= 5)
  {
  fibInt->length = 3;

  }
 }

 if(i == 0)
 {
     fatherFib->digits[0]= 0;
     grandfatherFib->digits[0]=1;
 }



fibInt = hugeAdd(fatherFib,grandfatherFib);

 grandfatherFib = fatherFib;


  if(fibInt->length == 2)
{
    printf("tens value in father fib %d\n", fatherFib->digits[1]);
}
fatherFib = fibInt;


}
 free(grandfatherFib->digits);
 free(grandFatherFib);
 return fatherFib;

}


int power(int base, int numTimes)
{
int result=1,i=0;

if(numTimes == 1)
{
    return base;
}

for(;i < numTimes; i++)
{
    result = result * base;
}
return result;
}
```

Comment: [Your code does not compile](https://godbolt.org/z/3jMMCy). `Any ideas?` - Create a reproducible example of the problem, post the output you are receiving and the output you expected to receive. Then ask, why do they differ. What does it mean "value of k is lost"? How do you "call a value (inside a loop)"? what does it mean "I get a memory address"? Memory address of what object, how do you check that it's a memory address?

Comment: Please post a [mcve]

Comment: Apart from turning this into a MCVE, please learn about and apply indentation.

Comment: You have checked the limit of `k` but index using `[k+1]`.

Comment: Let me try to see if i can trim it down

Comment: No, it is too small: it won't compile.

Comment: Not "trim" down. The "minimal" is not the problem. We would like something more "complete" and more "verifiable".

Comment: Why are you surprised to see a memory address? This line `if(p->digits[k+1] == NULL)` suggests the array is of pointers, but without the MCVE...

Comment: Post your code here, not at a download site.

Comment: Code is over 500 lines is that alright?

Comment: No, trim it down to just the parts that are relevant to the question.

Comment: If you work on constructing the MCVE that job itself may reveal the problem.

Comment: 500 lines are too long. Make a MCVE. Yes that is work, but necessary.

Comment: Ok let move some stuff around and i will see what i can do to get a solid MCVE.

Comment: It is a matter of taste and opinion, but I think your question was better with a little code than with none and a link. I recommend to go back and then edit to make a MCVE.

Comment: Yeah with all code it does compile and run

Comment: If you have gcc or MinGW behind CodeBlocks, open a terminal (that has the path to your compiler) and use `gcc -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -Wshadow -std=c11 -Ofast Fibonacci.c -o testcase04 testcase04.c` There are pages of warnings, some more notable, e.g. *"Fibonacci.c:29:40: warning: comparison between pointer and integer `else if(strlen(str) == 0 && str[0] == "")`"*  and *"comparison with string literal results in unspecified behavior"* `for(i=size-1; i != -1; i-- && j++)` and on... and on ....

Comment: Your last comment does not answer the last question in brunos comment.

Comment: A couple of other winners *"Fibonacci.c:116:5: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘free’ makes pointer from integer"* and *"Fibonacci.c:125:36: warning: initialization makes integer from pointer"* -- each individual one of the warnings is enough to send you spinning of into the realm of *Undefined Behavior*. Do not accept code until it compiles without warning (with full warnings enabled `:)`

Comment: I updated the code and posted a MCVE. Compiled and tested with codeblocks.

Comment: @bruno p->digits[k+1] == NULL is a check to see if 'k' went out of bounds with the carry integer then it would automatically add 1 to the final integer. Let me mess around with that part it doesn't look right.

Comment: @rob there are already too much remarks on your question, do remarks on my answer, I will delete some remarks here to limit their number, I encourage you to do the same ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Considering the warnings/errors when compiling your code :** (before question edition)

in Fibonacci.c

> ```
> else if(strlen(str) == 0 && str[0] == "")
> ```

`str[0]` is a *char*, `str[0] == ""` is never true, just do

```
else if (str[0] == 0)
```

In

> ```
> HugeInteger *hugeDestroyer(HugeInteger *p)
> {
>
>    int length;
>
>   // printf("Hiiting destroyer");
>    if(p == NULL)
>    {
>        return;
>    }
>
>    length = p->length;
>
>     free(p->digits); // But this works???????
>
>     free(p->length);
>     free(p);
>
>  }
> ```

you never return a value  ( a pointer to *HugeInteger*), visibly it must have the signature `void hugeDestroyer(HugeInteger *p)` (also in header)

In

> ```
> free(p->length);
> ```

you free an *int* ?

remove that line and also the other useless lines about *length*

so finaly

```
void hugeDestroyer(HugeInteger *p)
{
  // printf("Hiiting destroyer");
  if (p != NULL)
  {
    free(p->digits); // But this works???????
    free(p);
 }
}
```

In

> ```
>      unsigned long long int check = malloc(sizeof(unsigned long long int));
> ```

*malloc* return an address (pointer), and in fact you do not use *check* (`check = nextPow + real` is also useless)

difficult to imagine what you wanted to do with, remove all about *check*

In

> ```
>  if(p->digits[k+1] == NULL)
>  ...
>  if(p->digits[i+1] == NULL)
> ```

`p->digits[k+1]` is an *int*, you compare with a pointer, replace *NULL* by 0

In

> ```
> hugePrint(fibInt);
> ```

is unknown, its declaration is missing

**When you compile ask for high warning/error** detection level and correct your code in accordance

---

**Concerning the memory leaks :**

In *hugeAdd*

> ```
> HugeInteger *test = malloc(sizeof(HugeInteger));
> test->length= 1;
> test->digits = malloc(sizeof(int));
> test->digits[0] = 5;
> ```

*test* is never used after, you just create a meomry leak

> ```
>  resultArray = calloc(((p->length)+ overhead), sizeof(int));
> ```

you set its content but you never free it, it is an other memory leak

In *fib*

> ```
> HugeInteger *grandfatherFib = malloc(sizeof(HugeInteger));
> ```

you never free *grandfatherFib* this is an other memory leak

---

**Concerning the result :**

- fib(0) = 0 : ok
- fib(1) = 1 : ok
- fib(2) = 2 : ok
- ...
- fib(6) = 8 : ok
- fib(7) = 13 : ok
- fib(8) = 11 : ko

Your problem is you do not well add numbers with at least 2 digits, for instance if I change a little the end of *hugeAdd* toreplace

> ```
>  printf("Result array at 0 is %d\n", resultArray[0]); // This is were the 
>  printf("Result array at 1 is %d\n", resultArray[1]); // added numbers are stored.
>  printf("Result array at 2 is %d\n", resultArray[2]);
>  printf("=====================\n");
> ```

by the more practical

```
printf("=====================\n");
hugePrint(p);
puts("+");
hugePrint(q);
puts("=");
hugePrint(hugerInt);
printf("=====================\n");
```

and I do `fib(8)` that shows :

```
...
=====================
08
+
5
=
13
=====================
13
tens value in father fib 0
I is in larger then 9 check 0i is 0
Assigning 1 to 0 in resultarray
length of resultArray is 3
results:1

=================
=====================
13
+
08
=
11
=====================
```

you missed to **add** the carry : *8+3 = 11* so *1* and carry of *1* to add to *1* to have *21* rather than *11*

to have

```
if(results > 9 )
{
  printf("I is in larger then 9 check %d", i);
  if(p->digits[i+1] == 0)
  {
    hugerInt->digits[i+1] = 1;
  }
```

is not enough because the carry must be *added*, not set to 1 if valuing 0 (there is no else, only 0 become 1). Of course you may have to consider several changes, adding a carry of 1 to 999 produces 1000

Comment: Many good remarks. I don't understand the down votes (I upvoted).

Comment: @PaulOgilvie don't ask me, I don't know too ^^

Comment: @bruno cleaned up the MCVE, definitely compiles with no errors. Still cant figure out why i cant use 'k' in 'for(int k=0; k < p->length; k++)' to set a position in an array to 1.

Comment: @Rob you have a problem with the _carry_ look I edited my answer while you was writing your comment ^^

Comment: @bruno I looked at your comment and will try to figure it out how to properly add the carry.

Comment: @bruno THANK YOU!!!! I used 'calloc' instead of 'malloc' on the 'hugeInt' struct and made a couple changes to correctly add the carry. I spent a good 10+ hours or so trying to figure this out.

Comment: @Rob fine, good continuation, do not forget to correct also your memory leaks, use _valgrind_ to detect them

Comment: I don't understand why it has downvoted at all. Upvoted too

Comment: @snr there are surprisings behavior on S.O. ^^ Thank you :-)

Comment: @snr I DV'd the question as it was answering a question that lacked a clear problem statement and code.  The code then existed in an off site location and not here, thus this answer was not answering something that could certainly be reviewed in the future.  Answering such questions encourages that unhealthy non SO etiquette.  As OP has include code here how, I have voted to re-open and removed the DV here.

Comment: @chux Sir, I didn't think from the view point. In my name, I will be more sensitive about the case from now on.

Comment: @snr stay free to decide by yourself. My own point of view is if I can help an OP posting a question by answering, I do, even the question has some 'problems'. We are free to answer or not, and certainly not under the 'order' of some people whatever their reputation having a different thinking ...

Comment: @bruno Your saying is "generally" right. Yet, there are exception guys for me in this platform. I like to adopt ideas of "the masters". I don't care their reputations, however, if you glance at their answers, you see automagically their experiences and wisdom. Actually it's why their reputations are high. **While it is wise to learn from experience, it is wiser to learn from the experiences of others.”**